# Facebook Feed/Message for multiple ids at a time

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

Is there any option available for using multiple user message sending or feed wall post in FB?Tried with arrays for 'to' field, comma separated ids,......It only takes first id.

======================================================================

FB.init({appId: "APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

var obj = {
            method: 'send',
           redirect_uri: 'site_url',
            link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
            picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
            to:[fbid1,fbid2],
            name: ' testing name',
           caption: ' testing caption',
           description: 'testing to interact with users.'
           };

FB.ui(obj,callback );

======================================================================

Comment: Post some code and show us [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(yourFBIdsArray, function(index, fbid){
   FB.api('/'+fbid+'/photos', 'post', {
            message: messageToSend,
            url: ABSOLUTE_IMAGE_URL,      
        }, function(responseOne){
            if (!responseOne || responseOne.error) {
              //ERROR
            } else {
              //SUCCESS
            }
        });
});
```

You could do this. It will be slow but work. The example post a photo in the wall of the person with the facebook id passed.
You need also to ask permission {scope:'publish_stream'} when you do the app login.

Comment: FB.init({appId: "APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

I gave the correct application id still I am getting this error

code : 200
 
message : "(#200) This API call requires a valid app_id."

type  : "OAuthException"

Comment: Have you registered your app in https://developers.facebook.com/apps and put in that function the app id generated?

Comment: Yes application is already registered.It works fine with graph API.But I need it to work with feed post for multiple userids.Is there any solution for this